# scaling governor throws permission error for su

Tags: cpu-load

My cpu is burning it self if I dont put it powersave state.
recently widget on the top of my screen says 800Mhz but I know it is 1.733Ghz behind. I feel it because temp. passes 80 celcius (176 Fahrenheit).

Temp. is another problem, but I want to issue that command!

> nerkn@nerkn-laptop:/var/www/onyuz$ sudo echo -n powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor

but it throws

> bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied

I cant cry to say I'm super! Super user, no permission I know! Can any body suggest any thing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what the heat problem is, but I can tell you why your command failed: the redirect is set up *before* `sudo` is run, so you try to redirect it to `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor` as a normal user while the permissions don't allow that.

You can make a shell executes the whole command, including redirect, as root like this:

```
sudo sh -c "echo -n powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor"
```

Comment: nerkn@nerkn-laptop:/$ sudo echo powersave > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1: Is a directory

Comment: Ooops, I accidentally didn't copy the whole thing from your question, will fix that...

Answer (score 0):

Which CPU do you have? 800MHz is normal for many CPUs, if the CPU runs in Idle Mode. The CPU Clock will be reduced.

To run this bash command you have to add the sudo command

```
sudo bash ...
```

But try the *top* command first to look if there is a task running at 100%